# Cast/instantiate/convert to subclass/superclass without data duplication

Tags: c#, c++, objective-c, oop

It is a kind of OOP question, answer is wellcome for any of C++, C#, ObjC. 
In an application I have the following class structure.

```
class ToSend {
    public int id;
    public int prop1;
}

class Received : ToSend {
    public int prop2;
    public int prop3;
}

class Viewer : Received {
    public static int viewerProp;
    public String viewerMethod() {... Using viewerProp...}
}
```

Collection of class Received is received from a service. viewerMethod (Viewer) should be used for showing EACH items of the collection in a list. After a multiple selection and prop1 change, a collection of modifications (ToSend) should be sent back.

**Question 1:** how can I cast or convert ALL instances of Received to Viewer to use their viewerMethod?
Sould I use facade pattern? I do not want to copy the data, because it would take too much space.

**Question 2:** How sould I cast or convert selected instances of Received to ToSend to limit accessible properties? 
(After an explicit cast JSon encoder will include all properties of Received in the outgoing message)

Answer (score 3):

First ask yourself whether inheritance is the right solution here. A general rule of thumb is to express the relationship between the two classes in words.

If you say ClassA IS a ClassB, then in most cases you should use inheritance. For example, a Tiger IS a Mammal which IS an Animal. A tiger inherits all the properties common to all animals, plus the properties common to all mammals, plus some unique to its own species.

If you say ClassA HAS a ClassB, then in most cases you should use composition. For example, a Tiger HAS Teeth and Claws. But one would never say that a Tooth IS a tiger, so a Tooth class should never inherit from a Tiger class. Instead it should be a member variable of the Tiger class.

If a Viewer isn't a special case of a Received, it shouldn't inherit from Received.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use composition for the viewer rather than inheritance. After all, you didn't *receive* a viewer, you want to use a viewer to view the *data* that you received.

```
class Viewer
{
    public Viewer(Received received) 
    { 
        this.received = received;
    }

    private Received received;

    public string ViewerMethod() { ... }
}
```